# Begin a career as a core blockchain developer especially in EVM blockchains

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, ethers.js, etherscan, evm

I am highly interested in becoming a blockchain developer, but I am uncertain about where to commence and what to implement. I possess some knowledge of cryptography concepts such as RSA encryption and decryption, but I am unsure of how to apply them to blockchain development.

My primary objective is to build my blockchain by forking Geth, but I do not know where to start. I would appreciate any guidance or advice on how to get started with blockchain development, and how to utilize my cryptography knowledge to create a secure and dependable blockchain.

I am proficient in Go, Rust, and Solidity programming languages.

Therefore, I would be grateful for any suggestions on resources, tools, or tutorials that could help me learn more about blockchain development and how to create my blockchain. Thank you for your assistance!

(Note: By blockchain developer, I mean a core developer of the blockchain, not someone who develops dapps.)

Comment: Please accept the answer if it resolved your issue, or comment if you need any further help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forking geth is one possibility, of course... But maybe you would be better guided, and would have a lot more documentation, by checking Cosmos SDK and building your chain with that toolbox. It's also go based and you have various building blocks to play with and compose your blockchain as you envision it, but not needing to reinvent the wheel. Just an idea. Check more [here](https://v1.cosmos.network/sdk)

Comment: Does the cosmos sdk would help to understand how really  a blockchain work and what are the essential on it ? Becase i really want to understand or at least i'll try to understand everything about blockchain design

Comment: Exactly. Lot's of documentation and examples to play with. Good luck and welcome to the industry!

Comment: Thank you so much ! Have a good day !

Answer (score 0):

> My primary objective is to build my blockchain by forking Geth

GoEthereum is the oldest and one of the most legacy node applications. It means it is crufty and not that great in many aspects.

If you want to build your own blockchain start with

- [HyperSDK by Avalanche](https://github.com/ava-labs/hypersdk)
- [Cosmos SDK by Cosmos](https://v1.cosmos.network/sdk)

For the generic advise building a blockchain: just don't. The modern blockchains are so complex that minimum 50 people are needed to maintain a useful ecosystem. You are not going to create any value or add value to others by building your own blockchain.

Comment: Does the cosmos sdk and avax Hypersdk would help to understand how really  a blockchain work and what are the essential on it ? Becase i really want to understand or at least i'll try to understand everything about blockchain design

Comment: Yes, they would.

Comment: Thank you so much ! Have a good day !

Comment: Sorry but avalanche SDK isn't at all complete, it have a lot of thing missing